# Exportar datos de un <DIV> como .TXT

Tags: javascript, html

Encontré este código que me funciona perfecto para guardar como `.txt` los datos de un Input en HTML, sin embargo no me funciona para poder exportar los datos dentro de un `<DIV>`. Pues al abrir el archivo exportado sale "undefined".

Qué debo agregar para que funcione?

```js
function copiar(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Generate download of .txt file with some content
  var text = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var filename = "exportado.txt";

  copiar(filename, text);
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="input1">HOLA</textarea>
<button id="boton1">Exportar</button>
```

Comment: Jolin Oscar, iba a hacerlo yo :-)... ahora debemos esperar a que alguien más lo apruebe (si lo hago directo creo que no se necesitan votos)

Comment: Si es un div debes cambiar el .value por .innerHTML

Comment: Básicamente solo necesitas cambiar `var text = document.getElementById("input1").value;` por `var text = document.getElementById("input1").innerText;` cambiando el id `input1` por el id del div que quieres exportar.

Comment: Y no pongas el código en un enlace... lo que has hecho en el jsfiddle se puede reproducir perfectamente en un snippet (fragmento) y así la pregunta queda autocontenida y es perfecta (es lo que Oscar ha hecho, ha editado tu pregunta y te ha puesto el código en un snippet, pero no lo verás hasta que tu lo apruebes creo, o bien tenga más votos... yo ya he dado el mio pero faltan mas)

Comment: Una disculpa por no ponerlo incrustado, lo había puesto en JSFiddle porque en stackoverflow no se ejecutaba

Answer (score 1):

Para recuperar el texto del `div` tienes que usar la propiedad `textContent` en lugar de `value`. Tambien es bueno aclarar que no es lo mismo usar `innerHTML` en su lugar ya que copiara el `html` tal como esta como es con el caso de `&nbsp;` que pasara como un texto y no como un espacio.

```js
function copiar(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById('boton1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Generate download of .txt file with some content
  var text = document.querySelector('#div-text');
  var filename = 'exportado.txt';

  copiar(filename, text.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="div-text">Agrega un texto aqui: &nbsp;</div>

<button id="boton1">Exportar</button>
```

Comment: gracias! Funciona bien, pero porqué se exporta todo en una sola linea? Es decir, el div tiene textos uno debajo del otro  en <br> pero el código que has puesto los exporta inline

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba y los `<br />` si los reconoce como un salto de linea.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el contenido HTML dentro de un div, utilizar .innerHTML:

```
 var mayDiv = document.getElementById("mydivdata").innerHTML;
```

Para obtener el TEXTO dentro del div:

```
 var mayDiv = document.getElementById("mydivdata").innerText;
```

Comment: `innerHTML` no te exportará el texto del elemento, te exportará el código html de todo lo que tenga dentro.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez tiene razón, acabo de probarlo y lo exportó con todo y etiquetas. El código de Bladimir me funcionó, pero lo exporta todo en una sola linea, como soluciono eso? Por favor

Comment: @NotoriusSha usa `innerText` en lugar de `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, como me dijeron en los comentarios, bastó con reemplazar:

```
var text = document.getElementById("input1").value;
```

Por: `var text = document.getElementById("input1").innerText;`

Muchas gracias.

```js
function copiar(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Generate download of .txt file with some content
  var text = document.getElementById("input1").innerText;
  var filename = "exportado.txt";

  copiar(filename, text);
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="input1">HOLA</textarea>
<button id="boton1">Exportar</button>
```

Comment: que bien, éxitos estimado @NotoriusSha